# Python py2app setup.py error "ImportError: No module named sip"

Tags: python, macos, installation, setup.py, py2app

I'm using py2app to convert my python program to an .dmg on MacOS. The packages that I used are (Tkinter, Folium, and Pandas) and I have a few dependencies for the application to run. (.json, .cvs and .html) No matter what I do I get an error "ImportError: No module named sip"

Here is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

path_to_my_project = "/Users/my_name/Desktop/GeoProject"

APP = ['Map.py']
DATA_FILES = [
    ('dependencies', ['cityCoordinates.csv',
                      'shapefiles.json',
                      'Map.html',
                      'Map.spec',
                      'unitedStates.json'])
]

OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'packages': ['tk', 'folium', 'pandas']
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
    install_requires=['tk', 'folium', 'pandas'],
)
```

If I don't put DATA_FILES into a folder ('dependencies') I will get an error and that is the only way I could get it to work.